# android app work as Koisk

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I want to run my android tablet as kiosk. I want My application to start immediately after boot and remain always on Top. Mean User can not close application or view menu or other applications unless closing our app from given log-out option.

I am using android sdk with Eclipse n Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in manifest file -

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: ask to make your app homescreen so no matter if user press home your app will remain on top.

Comment: does it cater screen lock/unlock/standby or notifications. it's working well start at boot and disable menu but not status bar. I killed app using settings from menu bar.